# Upload files such as(image,video,docs) to my drive folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

basically I am creating an app where users can upload his/her files on drive by creating folders. Here I have been Successfully created a folder now the issue wt I am facing is how to upload files on that folder which the user just created.where the user can select multiple images, videos, docs, etc. For the select purpose, I have chosen intent but am not able to get how to upload it. Here's the code wt I have done till now.

For Creating Folder I used this method now I want to upload files in this folder please let me know

```
if (mDriveServiceHelper == null) {
                    return;
                }
                mDriveServiceHelper.createFolder("FolderNew", null)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleDriveFileHolder>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(GoogleDriveFileHolder googleDriveFileHolder) {
                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + gson.toJson(googleDriveFileHolder));
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getMessage());

                            }
                        });
```

For Picking Up Images And Videos

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
                if(data.getData()!=null){

                    Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);
                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            Toast.makeText(this, ""+uri, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(this, ""+imageEncoded, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(this, ""+imagesEncodedList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            cursor.close();

                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: `imagesEncodedList` ? What is in a name? What is encoded here? You got a nice uri and try to get a file system path using the .DATA column. Do away with this list completely. You do not need it. Also the .DATA column is not available in Android Q+.

Comment: `ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();` THAT IS YOUR LIST! Make it private to your activity. And also add the uri if only one file is selected. Then if you wanna upload your files use your uri list.

Comment: ok but my question is how to upload...